# Retain backslash in regex in 'gsub'

Tags: ruby, regex, string-literals

I want to replace spaces and forward slashes with an underscore, and retain backslashes.

How do I do this?

I have the following regex:

```
"hello\h /123".gsub(/[\s+\/]/, "_")
#=> "helloh__123"
```

But it also replaces backslashes in the string.

Comment: The backslash inside a double quoted string literal must be doubled. Or use a single quoted string literal. See https://ideone.com/NqLSk3

Comment: Your string does not have any backslashes in it.

Comment: If I put it in a variable it is coming as a='hello\c /123'.gsub(/\s+|\//, "_")
=> "hello\\c__123" .   But puts gives correct output. How to get it in variable?

Comment: @explorer `"hello\h /123"` is not the same as `'hello\h /123'`

Comment: `\h` is not an escape sequence. Therefore, `"\h"` is equivalent to `"h"`.  From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings): _"Any other character following a backslash is interpreted as the character itself."_

Answer (score 0):

So, if you just want to convert space and slash with underscore, you might prefer:

```
"hello\h /123".tr('/ ','__') # 2nd arg is two underscores
#=> "helloh__123"
```

(But I agree with the comments on the question so far.)